# unable to understand qr interpolation

Tags: regex, perl

I was reading Programming Perl where I learned `qr` interpolation of strings as regex as :

```
$re = qr/my.STRING/is;
print $re;                  # prints (?si-xm:my.STRING)
```

and it says

> The /s and /i modifiers were enabled in the pattern because they were
>   supplied to qr//. The /x and /m, however, are disabled because they
>   were not.

But this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use re 'debug';



my  $re = qr/abc/si;
my $string = qr/foo${re}bar/;

print "$string \n";  #prints(?^:foo(?^si:abc)bar)
```

Why `^` get added in my second program, I am not giving `^` explicitly in input, while the book

doesn't say it.Yes, I know what`?i:` means,
but I am not sure what `?^:` means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chapter of the Perl documentation that deals with this is called perlre. In the [extended pattern matching section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) it explains this.

> Starting in Perl 5.14, a "^" (caret or circumflex accent) immediately
>   after the "?" is a shorthand equivalent to d-imsx . Flags (except "d"
>   ) may follow the caret to override it. But a minus sign is not legal
>   with it.

So the `^` is not the beginning of the string. It is used for the sub-pattern to enable modifiers than the outside pattern.

Here's a simpler example:

```
my $first_re = qr{
foo # comment
}x;

my $second_re = qr/bar$first_re/i;

say $second_re;
```

The output of this is:

```
(?^i:bar(?^x:
foo # comment
))
```

The inside regex `$first_re` has the modifier `/x` in the sub-pattern `(?^x: ... )`. It also includes the comment and the new lines. The `/x` makes sure those are treated correctly.

The outside pattern `$second_re` has the `/i` modifier, but not `/x`. The inside one does not inherit the `/i`.

```
say 1 if 'BARFOO' =~ $second_re;
say 2 if 'BARfoo' =~ $second_re;
```

This will only print `2`.

Comment: that means ?^ in 5.14 or above is same as only ? in previous versions

Comment: No. It's a bit different. [@choroba pointed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30861899/1331451) to the [perldelta for 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perldelta.html#Regular-Expressions) which says _Stringification of regular expressions now uses this notation. For example, qr/hlagh/i would previously be stringified as (?i-xsm:hlagh) , but now it's stringified as (?^i:hlagh) ._.

Comment: @Arunesh Singh, No, `(?:PAT)` doesn't change the flags at all. `(?^:PAT)` means use the default flags.

Answer (score 3):

There was a change in 5.14.0 that added the "default modifiers" syntax. See [perldelta](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perldelta.html#Regular-Expressions).